# How to get the right jaxb object when having two elements under one list (jaxbObj.getAoAndBo() )?

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I'm using Java and JAXB for parsing a xml file.
I had a schema(xsd) that contains secquence element that contains two inner sequence element.

the xsd looks something like the following:

```
...
  <xs:element name="product_list">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="product">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence />
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="release" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="info">
    ...
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

After unmarshalling, when I want to fetch the list of "product", I get:

```
product_list.getProductsAndInfo()   => type: List<Object>
```

How can I get the information from the "product" object? (e.g product_list.getProduct)

Answer (score 0):

for getting the needed object information there is a need to use casting on the list of objects, for example:

ProductList pl = new ProductList(); // xml main object/element
pl= unmarshallfunc();
((ProductList.Product)pl.getProductAndInfo().get(0)).getName(); //type: List cast to Product.